# Is this Keras Sequential model learning?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to build a Keras Sequential model that fits my data. However, I have trouble choosing the layers and setting the input shape. My model accuracy starts with 0.4943 and doesn't change between epochs. It seems that my model is not learning.

The data looks like this:

```
X = [[[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [1.82562794e-01 6.81775296e-01]
  [1.13191538e+00 1.37766573e+00]
  ...
  [5.31509230e+01 4.88222520e+01]
  [5.38463488e+01 4.92077884e+01]
  [5.43891348e+01 4.98190918e+01]]

 [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [4.81657107e-01 4.62969773e-01]
  [1.33733394e+00 8.20860280e-01]
  ...
  [5.00154741e+01 4.49145568e+01]
  [5.06145436e+01 4.58551323e+01]
  [5.14753045e+01 4.66484598e+01]]

 [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [1.24209617e-01 3.41455813e-01]
  [6.62306377e-01 9.70226310e-01]
  ...
  [4.59534909e+01 5.14811676e+01]
  [4.65830639e+01 5.15458682e+01]
  [4.69169909e+01 5.18978055e+01]]

 ...

 [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [8.37513698e-01 2.36545136e-01]
  [2.09606414e+00 2.18579855e+00]
  ...
  [9.33516241e+01 9.02639438e+01]
  [9.48198248e+01 9.09696034e+01]
  [9.56924057e+01 9.11994364e+01]]

 [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [1.16628793e+00 3.07939104e-01]
  [2.90856042e+00 1.93300849e+00]
  ...
  [9.50615310e+01 9.54437621e+01]
  [9.64466547e+01 9.62387560e+01]
  [9.84132452e+01 9.68517902e+01]]

 [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [7.07518408e-02 1.63762559e+00]
  [1.47380576e+00 3.01519861e+00]
  ...
  [9.56341427e+01 8.22719298e+01]
  [9.75264435e+01 8.41242858e+01]
  [9.85001877e+01 8.44169342e+01]]]

X.shape = (2000, 100, 2)

y = [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]

y.shape = (2000,)
```

and here is the model code:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(100,2)),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

h = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=3, shuffle=True)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
```

I am trying to do a binary classification. Is there something wrong with my model?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try changing the number of dense units in layers. A better approach would be to use the 2/3 number of dense units in the current layer of the number of dense units in the previous layer.

Comment: @DhavalTaunk Thank you. Do you have any comments on the value of input_shape parameter? I think I am making a mistake here.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed your `batch_size=3` which is not a good choice. Try experimenting with different architectures/parameters. Here's a simple one to go with:

```
model = Sequential()
# model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=X.shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu')
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```

**Working example:**

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

# sample data, 100 samples
X_train = np.random.random((100,2)) 
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 1)) 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=2)
model.predict(X_train).shape # (100, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @YOLO. I am having some trouble with specifying the correct value to input_dim parameter. Setting input_dim equal to 2 causes an error. Could you please help me set that parameter as well?

Comment: check the edit. you can either use `input_shape` parameter.

Comment: I guess X.shape is not a correct value for input_shape, because X.shape is (2000, 100, 2) and 2000 is the batch size which shouldn't be given to input_shape parameter. I get an error when I set input_shape to (100, 2), or (2000, 100, 2).
@YOLO

Comment: sorry, in your case it should be `input_shape=(100,2)` we don't pass the batch size in the shape

Comment: Thank you. When I set `input_shape=(100,2)`, I get this error:
`ValueError: A target array with shape (1400, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 100, 1) while using as loss binary_crossentropy. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.`
Any thoughts on this?
P.S. The training batch size is 1400.

Comment: Check edit. modify your data according to my example.

Comment: I am expecting to get one y value for each array of 100 points with (x1, x2) values. I changed my code according to your edit, but when I try to predict y value for a new point, I get 100 y values instead of one. However, I want to predict one y value based on 100 (x1, x2) values each time. For example, I am trying to predict if an object is walking or driving, based on its 100 recent (latitude, longitude) values. I expect to get a label of 'walking' or 'driving' as I pass 100 (latitude, longitude) values.

Comment: I've fixed the bug, please check.

Comment: I'm sorry but this update doesn't seem to solve my problem. In your code, `X_train[0]` is something like `[0.66560401 0.62253082]`. However, I want each training example to have the shape of (100, 2) such that `X_train[i].shape = (100, 2)` for each `i` between 1 and 1400.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205346/discussion-between-yolo-and-zahra-golpa).

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this question, I realized that changing the input shape to (200, ) fixes the problem. Things get complicated when you add dimensions to your data. Thank you @YOLO for helping me.